# Histogram calculation in julia-lang

Tags: histogram, julia

refer to julia-lang documentations :

> hist(v[, n]) → e, counts

Compute the histogram of v, optionally using approximately n bins. The return values are a range e, which correspond to the edges of the bins, and counts containing the number of elements of v in each bin. Note: Julia does not ignore NaN values in the computation.

I choose a sample range of data

```
testdata=0:1:10;
```

then use hist function to calculate histogram for 1 to 5 bins

```
hist(testdata,1) # => (-10.0:10.0:10.0,[1,10])
hist(testdata,2) # => (-5.0:5.0:10.0,[1,5,5])
hist(testdata,3) # => (-5.0:5.0:10.0,[1,5,5])
hist(testdata,4) # => (-5.0:5.0:10.0,[1,5,5])
hist(testdata,5) # => (-2.0:2.0:10.0,[1,2,2,2,2,2])
```

as you see when I want 1 bin it calculates 2 bins, and when I want 2 bins it calculates 3.

why does this happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the person who wrote the underlying function: the aim is to get bin widths that are "nice" in terms of a base-10 counting system (i.e. 10<sup>k</sup>, 2×10<sup>k</sup>, 5×10<sup>k</sup>). If you want more control you can also specify the exact bin edges.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think some lack of documentation exists there.

Comment: Is there an easy way to plot the results of the hist function?

Comment: Yes - `using StatsBase; h = fit(Histogram, randn(1000)); using StatPlots; plot(h)`

Comment: This function seems to be deprecated in `Base` module. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 5):

The key word in the doc is *approximate*. You can check what `hist` is actually doing for yourself in Julia's `base` module [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/statistics.jl#L653).

When you do `hist(test,3)`, you're actually calling

```
hist(v::AbstractVector, n::Integer) = hist(v,histrange(v,n))
```

That is, in a first step the `n` argument is converted into a `FloatRange` by the `histrange` function, the code of which can be found [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/statistics.jl#L593). As you can see, the calculation of these steps is not entirely straightforward, so you should play around with this function a bit to figure out how it is constructing the range that forms the basis of the histogram.

Answer (score 1):

In new versions of Julia, the `hist` function is not present.

To calculate a histogram, one should use `StatsBase.Histogram` and `StatsBase.fit`, e.g.:

```
    using StatsBase
    h = fit(Histogram, rand(100))
    print(h)
```

Output:

```
Histogram{Int64, 1, Tuple{StepRangeLen{Float64, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Int64}}}
edges:
  0.0:0.2:1.0
weights: [21, 22, 17, 16, 24]
closed: left
isdensity: false
```